# Function doesn't accept updated value React JS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

ascendingDirectionSort has 'true' initial value. It can be changed by dropdownlist. When it is changed, console.log in the sortData function shows updated value, but only the ascendingDirectionSort==true condition executes, even when it's false.

```js
   ...Class
   ...constructor
this.state={
  ascendingDirectionSort:true
}
render()...
const {ascendingDirectionSort}=this.state


const sortData(field)=>{
  console.log(ascendingDirectionSort)//true, when ascendingDirectionSort=true and false when = false
  if(ascendingDirectionSort){
  execute1...//always executes
  console.log(ascendingDirectionSort)
  }else{
  execute2...//doesnt work
  
  }

}
...
   <select value = {ascendingDirectionSort} onChange={this.handleChange}>
        <option value={true}>Ascending</option>
        <option value={false}>Descending</option>
    </select>
...

handleChange = (event) => {
  this.setState({ ascendingDirectionSort: event.target.value });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> <option value={true}>
> ```

While you are passing boolean values to the `value` props, they will be rendered as HTML attributes and so will be converted to **strings**.

> ```
> if(ascendingDirectionSort){
> ```

You are testing the truthiness of the value of that variable.

`true`, `"true"` and `"false"` are **all** *true* values.

---

Use strings consistently.

```
this.state={
  ascendingDirectionSort:"true"
}
```

and

```
if(ascendingDirectionSort === "true"){
```